# Calling AcceptTcpClient on sockect never continues in a win application

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote the code as seen below as a C# console app, and it works correctly.
However when I use in win application it dose not work.

I put in a break point, and it stops on " tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();" line,
and does not do any work and does not show any thing, and no errors are returned.

part of my code :

```
   void _func_send()
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[512];

        IPAddress add = ipHost.AddressList[2];
        Socket server = new Socket(add.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        TcpListener tcpListener = null;
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(add, 50);
        //tcpListener.Stop();

        tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {

               /////on this line it stops
            tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            if (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                _txt_show.Text = _txt_show.Text + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(".:: thanks ::.");
                stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you have something else on the other side of the connection sending data to this program?

Comment: Is this not because TcpListner.AcceptTcpClient is a blocking call thus the code does not move until a client is connected?

Comment: I updated your title to more reflect what you are asking. Please check if I edited in a way that suits you.

Comment: Your code is the server side of the socket. Where or what is the client side of the socket doing?

Comment: Like @user2509919 says - it sounds like its not doing any work because there is no work to do, (until a client connects). It doesn't return an error because there has been no error.

Comment: ..and anyway, your code looks odd.  It's by no means certain that there is data available after the accept() returns and stream.DataAvailable is not a blocking call. You then loop back to accept() and don't get to read anything from the 'tcpClient' server<>client socket.

Comment: i have a module and computer.server side code is on computer and client code is on module.i got answer by console but not by win app.